# access object in C#

Tags: c#, class, object

I have a class proxy, Process Track Manager.

To the constructor of the Proxy I sent an instance of Process class. Process class has a list
As

```
public List<TrackManager> l = new List<TrackManager>();
```

I add 2 instance of track manager to the list.

From another class call UpdateClient, how do I access the method of the TrackManager in the list?

Comment: Could you add a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to implement a method from your first class, for example:

```
//Class Example
    public void UpdateClient(int n){
l[n].myMethod();
}
```

Then in the class you want to instance your object you could do this:
(Asuming you have an object "Example" built in your constructor, or somewhere before):

```
public void RandomMethod()
{
//code...
    ex.updateClient(n);
//Being ex an instance of the class Example
}
```